# Scalecodec: How can I get the equivalent of Decode in Python, instead of DecodeAll?

Tags: rust, rpc, scale-codec, python, scale

When using the Python script:

```
timestamp = ScaleDecoder.get_decoder_class('Timestamp', ScaleBytes(timestamp_bytes_array)).decode()
```

it seems that the decoder expects the size of the array to be exactly equal to the object to be decoded. This is equivalent to the behavior of the `DecodeAll` trait in rust, where the remaining bytes after decoding must be zero.

How can I, in Python, do whatever is equivalent to `Decode` trait in rust, where the number of remaining bytes, after decoding, can be > 0, so that I can decode a stream?

Comment: After weeks of posting the question, I'm starting to wonder whether there's no way to do this at all... really weird. I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is kwarg you can pass to the `decode()` function, so it won't check the remaining bytes: `decode(check_remaining=False)`.

I don't have much context of your use-case, but I assume you have added a custom type definition `Timestamp` to the type registry? Because by default there is no type with that name.

Comment: Thank you very much! I almost thought this sub is abandoned.